# Error in Output : C++ Carpet Store

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment in C++ but i am relatively new to the C++ programming language, however, I am getting errors in my output.

**Question**

The manager of the Crosswell Carpet Store has asked you to write a program to print customers’ bills. The manager has given you the following information:

- The length and width of a room are expressed in terms of meters and centimeters. For example, the length might be reported as 16.7 meters.
- The store does not sell fractions of a meter.  Thus, the length and width must always be rounded up.
- The carpet charge is equal to the number of square meters purchased times the carpet cost per square meter.  Sales tax equal to 14% of the carpet cost must be added to the bill.
- The labour cost is equal to the number of square meters purchased times R24.00, which is the labor cost per square meter. No tax is charged on labour.
- Each customer is identified by a five-digit number, and that number should appear on the bill.   Large-volume customers, identified by a customer number starting with a '0', may be given a discount.  The discount applies to the cost before sales tax is added.
  The sample output follows:

  ```
  CROSWELL CARPET STORE STATEMENT
  Customer name : xxxxx
  Customer number : xxxxx
  Carpet price : xx.xx
  Labour : xx.xx
  Subtotal : xx.xx
  Less discount : xx.xx
  Subtotal : xx.xx
  Plus tax : xx.xx
  Total : xx.xx
  ```

And my answer to this question is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int calculateCarpetSize (int length, int width)
{
    int carpetSize;
    carpetSize = ceil(length * width);
    return carpetSize;
}

float calculateCarpetCost (int carpetSize , float sellingPrice)
{
    float carpetCost;
    carpetCost = carpetSize * sellingPrice;
    return carpetCost;
}

float calculateLabourCost(int carpetSize)
{
    float labourCost;
    labourCost = carpetSize * 24.00;
    return labourCost;
}

bool qualifyForDiscount(string customerNo)
{
    string dis = "0";
    if (customerNo.compare(0, dis.length(), dis) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}

float computeDiscount ()
{
    int discountPercentage;
    float discount;
    cout << "Enter the Percetage Discount: ";
    cin >> discountPercentage ;
    discount = discountPercentage / 100;
    return discount;
}

void printCustomerStatement(string customerName, string customerNo, float carpetCost, float labourCost, float discount)
{
    float subtotal = carpetCost + labourCost - discount;
    float vat = subtotal*0.14;
    cout << "\n      CROSWELL CARPET STORE"<<endl;
    cout << "            STATEMENT"<<endl;
    cout << "Customer name   : "<<customerName<<endl;
    cout << "Customer number : "<<customerNo <<'\n'<<endl;
    cout << "Carpet price    : "<<carpetCost<<endl;
    cout << "Labour          : "<<labourCost <<'\n'<<endl;
    cout << "Subtotal        : "<<carpetCost+labourCost<<endl;
    cout << "Less discount   : "<<discount <<'\n'<<endl;
    cout << "Subtotal        : "<<subtotal<<endl;
    cout << "Plus Tax        : "<<vat<<endl;
    cout << "Total           : "<<subtotal - vat<<endl;
}
int main()
{
     string customerName;
     string customerNo;
     float carpetSize;
     float sellingPrice;
     float length;
     float width;
     float carpetCost;
     float labourCost;
     float discount;
    cout <<"ENTER CUSTOMER NAME:";
    cin >>customerName;
    cout <<"ENTER CUSTOMER NUMBER:";
    cin >>customerNo;
    cout <<"ENTER ROOM WIDTH:";
    cin >>width;
    cout <<"ENTER ROOM LENGTH:";
    cin >>length;
    cout <<"ENTER SELLING PRICE:";
    cin >>sellingPrice;
    calculateCarpetSize(length, width);
    calculateCarpetCost(carpetSize, sellingPrice);
    calculateLabourCost(carpetSize);
    if(qualifyForDiscount(customerNo))
    {
        computeDiscount();
    }else
    {
        discount = 0.00;
    }
    printCustomerStatement(customerName, customerNo, carpetCost, labourCost, discount);
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem may be my function or my datatypes, or perhaps both.

**EDIT**

I get an output of this sort

```
ENTER CUSTOMER NAME:Quatban
ENTER CUSTOMER NUMBER:02234
ENTER ROOM WIDTH:20
ENTER ROOM LENGTH:20
ENTER SELLING PRICE:35
ENTER DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE: 2

  CROSWELL CARPET STORE
        STATEMENT
Customer name   : Quatban
Customer number : 02234

Carpet price    : 1.4e+004
Labour          : 9.6e+003

Subtotal        : 2.4e+004
Less discount   : 0

Subtotal        : 2.4e+004
Plus Tax        : 3.3e+003
Total           : 2e+004
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: you should review how you store the return values from your functions, as a starting point (eg carpetSize = calculateCarpetSize(length, width);

Comment: @MartinZhai, The output is incorrect, Perhaps if you can compile the code to see the output it generates.

Answer (score 0):

### First

> Thus, the length and width must always be rounded up

Which means your function `calculateCarpetSize` should look more like :

```
int calculateCarpetSize (float length, float width)
{
    int carpetSize;
    carpetSize = ceil(length) * ceil(width);
    return carpetSize;
}
```

### Then

In your main :

```
calculateCarpetSize(length, width);
calculateCarpetCost(carpetSize, sellingPrice);
calculateLabourCost(carpetSize);
```

You should be storing the result of these functions like :

```
carpetSize = calculateCarpetSize(length, width);
carpetCost = calculateCarpetCost(carpetSize, sellingPrice);
labourCost = calculateLabourCost(carpetSize);
```

---

### Edit

This actually gives you as output :

```
ENTER CUSTOMER NAME:Quatban
ENTER CUSTOMER NUMBER:02234
ENTER ROOM WIDTH:20
ENTER ROOM LENGTH:20
ENTER SELLING PRICE:35
Enter the Percetage Discount: 2

      CROSWELL CARPET STORE
           STATEMENT
Customer name   : Quatban
Customer number : 02234

Carpet price    : 14000
Labour          : 9600

Subtotal        : 23600
Less discount   : 0

Subtotal        : 23600
Plus Tax        : 3304
Total           : 20296
```

This looks like your (expected ?) result, even if I believe the last line should be `subtotal + tax` and not `subtotal - tax` but I may be wrong.